# Middleman shows syntax error when using a link_to block

Tags: syntax, erb, link-to, middleman, middleman-4

I'm using Middleman 4.2 with Middleman-blog 4.0.2.

When I have:

```
<% blog.tags.each do |tag, articles| %>
   <%= link_to "#{tag.titleize} - #{articles.size}", tag_path(tag) %>
<% end %>
```

I get the desired `<a>` element output:

`<a href="/blog/posts/tags/test-tag/">Test Tag - 1</a>`

But when I change the `link_to` to a block:

```
<% blog.tags.each do |tag, articles| %>
   <%= link_to tag_path(tag) do %>
      <%= tag.titleize %> - <%= articles.size %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I get a syntax error:

```
/source/blog/index.html.erb:43: syntax error, unexpected ')' ...<< ( link_to tag_path(tag) do ).to_s; @_out_buf << '
```

I can't seem to figure out why I'm not able to get the same output here.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized I had the wrong erb tag on the line with the link_to helper.

The correct code looks like this:

```
<% blog.tags.each do |tag, articles| %>
   <% link_to tag_path(tag) do %>
      <%= tag.titleize %> - <%= articles.size %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```